# HTML parsing with php

Tags: php, dom

Can anyone help in parsing this part of an HTML site? I use php and PHP:DOM
I would like to get the Klassifikation and Schlagwörter in one php string.
How is this done?
Thanks

```
    <tr style="display:table-row;">
    <td id="TREFWOORD" class="onOffLink"></td>
    <td class="rec_lable"><div>
     <span>Schlagwörter</span><span>: </span>
    </div></td>
    <td class="rec_title"><div>
    <span>*</span><span><a class="
        link_gen
        " href="MAT=/NOMAT=T/REL?PPN=106189719">Recht</a></span><span> 
    </span><span><a href="http://" 
   target=""><img src="http://" 
 alt="Subject" title="Subject" class="img_link"></a></span><span> / </span> 
 <span><a class="
        link_gen
        " href="MAT=/NOMAT=T/CMD? 
ACT=SRCHA&amp;IKT=5040&amp;TRM=Wo%CC%88rterbuch">Wörterbuch</a></span>
 </div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr style="display:table-row;">
<td></td>
<td class="rec_lable"><div><span>Klassifikation: </span></div></td>
<td class="rec_title"><div>
 <span>Basisklassifikation: </span><span><a class="
        link_gen
        "  target=""><img 
 src="http://" alt="Subject" 
 title="Subject" class="img_link"></a></span>
</div></td>
</tr>
```

I tried this without success:

```
<?php                    

$url='http://...'
$easycurlcmd=sprintf("curl '%s' -o ./libbvhtml.txt", $url);                    
printf("Execute: CURL1 ".$easycurlcmd."\n");                    
exec($easycurlcmd);                    

$html=file_get_contents('./libbvhtml.txt');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$rec_lable = $xpath->query("//tr/*[contains(@class, rec_lable')]/div/span[1]");

echo $rec_lable->item(0)->nodeValue; // SchlagwÃ¶rter                    
echo $rec_lable->item(1)->nodeValue; // Klassifikation
```

The reason was that curl must be defined with the redirect option.
Thanks to all.

Comment: _"I use php and PHP:DOM"_  - Where's that code? We can help with your _existing_ code, but we're not here to write it all for you.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I do know, but How to start with? I could learn from Mohammads reply very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to parsing HTML and use [`DOMXPath::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) to searching in DOM.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$rec_lable = $xpath->query("//tr/*[contains(@class, 'rec_lable')]/div/span[1]");
echo $rec_lable->item(0)->nodeValue; // SchlagwÃ¶rter
echo $rec_lable->item(1)->nodeValue; // Klassifikation
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/BBovF)

Comment: thanks: BUt I need the values for the Klassifikation: f.e see above The Result should be: Klassifikation: 86.00 (Recht: Allgemeines). Do you know wher I could learn more about this great $xpath->query?

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I could find it out:  `    $rec_lable = $xpath->query("//tr/*[contains(@class, 'rec_title')]/div/span[2]");`